# How to get rid of tkinter frame and canvas border

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

In the code below, I am trying to remove the border of the canvas or the edge of the frame the canvas is inside on each of the cells, however, I have set bd=0 and borderwidth=0 for the frame and canvas respectively and colour them the same as the background colour but it still has not succeeded. Has anybody experienced this before. I use the online IDE Replit so I apologise for the layout beforehand if anybody runs it but I am also interested to know if that might make a difference or not.
Thanks

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox as m

WOODEN="#BA8C63"
PALE_BLUE="#CDF5F6"
PALE_YELLOW="#EFF9DA"
PALE_RED="#F9D8D6"
PALE_GREEN="#DDF0C7"
PALE_PINK="#D6CDEA"

class Game(tk.Tk):

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.geometry("975x210")
    self.configure(bg=WOODEN)
    self.resizable(False, False)
    self.title("Mancala")
    self.P1pits={"Bank":Bank(self,"P1"),"Pits":[Pit(self,"P1",i) for i in range(1,9)]}
    self.P2pits={"Bank":Bank(self,"P2"),"Pits":[Pit(self,"P2",i) for i in range (1,9)]}
    self.mainloop()


class Cell(tk.Frame):

  def __init__(self,master,height,BG):
    super().__init__(master=master,width=80,height=height,bg=BG,borderwidth=0)
    self.amount=0
    self.start_canvas()
    self.redraw()

  def start_canvas(self):
    self.canv=tk.Canvas(self,width=80,height=80,bg=WOODEN,bd=0)
  
  def redraw(self):
    self.canv.pack()


class Bank(Cell):

  def __init__(self,master,player):
    super().__init__(master,148,WOODEN)
    self.player=player
    self.counters=[]
    self.enlarge_canvas()
    self.add_pot()
    if player == "P1":
      self.grid(row=0,column=9,rowspan=2,pady=(7,10),padx=(10,15))
    else:
      self.grid(row=0,column=0,rowspan=2,pady=(10,7),padx=(15,10))

  def enlarge_canvas(self):
    self.canv.configure(height=180)

  def add_pot(self):
    self.p1=self.canv.create_arc((2,2,78,78),start=0,extent=180)
    self.p2=self.canv.create_arc((2,102,78,178),start=180,extent=180)
    self.p3=self.canv.create_line(2,40,78,40,fill=WOODEN)
    self.p4=self.canv.create_line(2,140,78,140,fill=WOODEN)
    self.p5=self.canv.create_line(2,40,2,140)
    self.p6=self.canv.create_line(78,40,78,140)


class Pit(Cell):

  def __init__(self,master,player,index):
    super().__init__(master,80,WOODEN)
    self.amount=6
    self.counters=[]
    self.add_pot()
    if player == "P1":
      self.grid(row=1,column=index,pady=(7,12),padx=4)
    else:
      self.grid(row=0,column=9-index,pady=(12,7),padx=4)

  def add_pot(self):
    self.p1=self.canv.create_oval(1,1,79,79)
      

def again(val):
  global window
  window.destroy()
  if val:
    window = Game()


if __name__ == "__main__":
  window = Game()
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set `highlightthickness=0` when creating the canvas:

```py
def start_canvas(self):
  self.canv=tk.Canvas(self,width=80,height=80,bg=WOODEN,bd=0,highlightthickness=0)
```

Comment: That worked! (Not surprised, just happy). Thank you very much